# Allocating memory to char pointers

Tags: c, pointers, allocation

I have two issues with a function, one very hindering and the other not quite so.

I'm in the process of learning C, and the following (reduced for ease of reading) main, and findWord functions should store a randomly chosen word into 'wordToGuess' from a .txt file.

findWord stores the word into the pointer 'wordToGuess' just fine but I can't seem to extract it from the function to use it in the main. I tried making the function a 'void' and directly modifying 'wordToGuess' within the function, and making it a char* returning the word to then be used by the main, to no avail. No issues with the int* wordLength in either case, making me think the issue would stem either from a latent misunderstanding of pointers or of memory allocation.

The other less important issue is that free(wordToFind) crashes the whole thing somehow, but I'm not as fussed about that issue.

Thanks for any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MIN 0
#define MAX 10
#define WORDSIZE 40

char* findWord(char *wordToGuess , int *wordLength);


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int *wordLength = NULL , lengthWord = 0;
    char *wordToGuess = NULL ;

    srand(time(NULL));                                              // For rand() in findWord

    wordLength = &lengthWord;

    printf("\n1: %s\n" , findWord(wordToGuess , wordLength);        // Sole purpose of this tester printf is to verify findWord function

    return 0;
}


char* findWord(char *wordToGuess , int *wordLength)
{
    int wordNumber = 0 , i = 0;
    char word[WORDSIZE] = {0};

    FILE *wordFile = NULL;

    wordFile = fopen("words.txt" , "r");

    if(wordFile != NULL)
    {
        wordNumber = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;                  // Random number to choose word form words.txt

        for(i = 0 ; i < wordNumber ; i++)
        {
            while(fgetc(wordFile) != '\n');                             // Move the cursor to line 'wordNumber'
        }

        fgets(word , WORDSIZE , wordFile);                              // Get word from that line
    }

    *wordLength = strlen(word);

    wordToGuess = malloc(*wordLength * sizeof(char));
    if(wordToGuess == NULL)
        exit(0);

    wordToGuess = word;

    fclose(wordFile);

   // free(wordToGuess);

    return wordToGuess;
```

}

Comment: `wordToGuess = word;` or `strcpy()`?? what do you want?

Comment: First, `strlen` does not include the terminating `null` byte. And the real problem is `wordToGuess = word` your are assigning the address of a local variable to your pointer. You should use `memcpy`.

Comment: I think the poster is biting more than what he can chew. Luke, before you try to tackle exercises of this scale, you need to learn the basics of pointers and memory management in C using much smaller programs.

Comment: Comment box says to avoid comments like "thanks", so I'll just thank everyone for their answers here, all very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *many* problems with your code. First and foremost is that C passes arguments *by value*, that means they are copied when you pass arguments to functions. So inside a function, all you have is a *copy*, and modifying a copy will of course not modify the original.

C doesn't have pass *by reference*, but it can be emulated by using pointers. In your case, you have to pass a pointer to the pointer. This can be done using the address-of operator `&`. Of course you have to modify the function to be able to take a pointer to a pointer as its first argument.

You are, in a way, doing it right now with the `wordLength` argument, ***but*** you declare it to be a pointer in the calling function, and a pointer to `NULL` which means that dereferencing it inside the function will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

So somewhat correct code would be something like

```
char* findWord(char **wordToGuess , int *wordLength);

int main()
{
    int wordLength = 0;
    char *wordToGuess = NULL;

    printf("%s\n", findWord(&wordToGuess, &wordLength));
    // Note use of address-of operator
}
```

Then in the `findWord` function, you of course have to dereference the pointer to the string, e.g.

```
*wordToGuess = malloc(...);
```

There are also *other* errors in the `findWord` function, like you re-assigning to the pointer instead of copying to it, that will make you loose the original pointer you allocate, and make it point to a local variable and will not be valid once the function returns. Instead *copy* to the memory.

Another major problem in the `findWord` function is that you allocate one byte to little. Remember that strings contain one more character than reported by `strlen`, and that is the string terminator character `'\0'`. When you allocate memory you must add space for this character.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign

```
wordToGuess = word;
```

you overwrite the handle to the allocated memory and effectively lose it. Even worse, you make `wordToGuess` point to a local array that goes out of scope as soon as you return from the function.

Your idea to allocate memory for the string that you return is good, but you have to copy the contents of the string, not the string address:

```
strcpy(wordToGuess, word);
```

You must allocate one char more than the `strlen` for the terminating null character, which will also be copied with `strcpy`.

If your system has `strdup` you can use it to allocate and copy in one go.

Answer (score 2):

first you allocate memory for the string

```
wordToGuess = malloc(*wordLength * sizeof(char));
```

then you immediately overwrite the pointer

```
wordToGuess = word;
```

that means: 
1) wordToGuess now points to a buffer that will be invalid as soon as the function returns 
2) the allocated memory is now orphaned

you probably want `strcpy`
you also have to allocate memory for the trailing '\0', so `malloc( 1 + *wordLength )`
note that `sizeof(char)` is 1 per definition

Answer (score 2):

It's not a memory allocation problem.
You have initialized the array with {0} and tried to assign it with the "=" operator.

Array values are **NOT** modifiable in C so you can't just say:

```html
wordToGuess = word;
```

You can change the content of an array, but not by doing something like pointer_a = pointer_b, instead, use strcpy, in your case:

```html
strcpy(wordToGuess, word);
```

or *strcpy_s*, which provides the same result, but won't cause a buffer overrun if you correctly specify the size of the destination buffer.

Comment: `word` is the array, he doesn't try to assign to that.

Answer (score 1):

Yout have two important problems here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MIN 0
#define MAX 10
#define WORDSIZE 40

char* findWord(int *wordLength);


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int lengthWord = 0;
    char *wordToGuess;

    srand(time(NULL));                                              // For rand() in findWord
    wordToGuess =  findWord(&lengthWord);
    if (wordToGuess != NULL)
    {       
        printf("\n1: %s\n" , wordToGuess);        // Sole purpose of this tester     printf is to verify findWord function
        free(wordToGuess); // you should release resources.
    }
    return 0;
}


char* findWord(int *wordLength) // You don't need to pass wordToGuess as a parameter.
{
    int wordNumber = 0 , i = 0;
    char word[WORDSIZE] = {0};
    char *wordToGuess;

    FILE *wordFile = NULL;

    wordFile = fopen("words.txt" , "r");

    if(wordFile != NULL)
    {
        wordNumber = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;                  // Random number to choose word form words.txt

        for(i = 0 ; i < wordNumber ; i++)
        {
            while(fgetc(wordFile) != '\n');                             // Move the cursor to line     'wordNumber'
        }

        fgets(word , WORDSIZE , wordFile);                              // Get word from that line
    }

    *wordLength = strlen(word);

    //wordToGuess = malloc(*wordLength * sizeof(char)); // this is wrong
    wordToGuess = malloc(*wordLength + 1); // sizeof(char) equals 1 always
    if(wordToGuess == NULL)
        exit(0);

    // wordToGuess = word; this line is wrong, it should be
    memcpy(wordToGuess, word, *wordLength);
    wordToGuess[*wordLength] = '\0';

    fclose(wordFile);

   // free(wordToGuess);

    return wordToGuess;
}
```

You should always allocate space for the `null` terminating byte, and you should learn how pointers work, since it is clear you don't understand them from `wordToGuess = word;`.

Comment: there is no reason the `wordToGuess` goes in as a parameter